# Reading xml value from left to right in a table column

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Hi I am trying to create a dynamic table that can be populated with XML Data. There are two rows and three columns in the table. The first row should be the "@n1three" and the second row should populate the "@n1three3" data. Inside of the xml tag n1third, there are three values to populate the columns. This might not always be the case, it could only be two, but three columns should remain whether there is data or not.

I can get the data to read out, but never in the correct format. Below is my code for the XML and HTML. Can someone shed some light. Thanks.

XML:

```
<numberNodes>
 <node pos="1">
  <n1first n1first="a1">
<n1second n1second="aa2">
   <n1third n1three = "aaa1" n1three3="23"/>
   <n1third n1three = "aaa2" n1three3="24"/>
   <n1third n1three = "aaa3" n1three3="25"/>
  </n1second>
   <n1second n1second="aa2">
   <n1third n1three = "aaa1" n1three3="23"/>
   <n1third n1three = "aaa2" n1three3="23"/>
   <n1third n1three = "aaa3" n1three3="23"/>
  </n1second>
 </n1first>
 </node>
</numberNodes>
```

HTML:

```
<table border="16" cellspacing="2">
 <xsl:for-each select="n1third">
<tr><td><xsl:value-of select="@n1three"/></td></tr>
  <tr>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="@n1three3"/></td>
  </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Comment: I have no idea what's being asked here.

Comment: Your second sample isn't HTML, it's the XSLT code you're using to try and produce the HTML. Can you post a sample of the final HTML output you actually want to get based on that XML? Then we'll be able to help you modify the XSLT to create it.

Comment: In your XML input sample, you have enough **n1third** elements to populate two tables. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot be sure that you have 3 n1third input values, you'll have to use recursion:

```
<table border="16" cellspacing="2">
  <tr>
    <xsl:call-template name="writeRow">
       <xsl:with-param name="input" select="n1third/@n1three"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="cellCount" select="3"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <xsl:call-template name="writeRow">
       <xsl:with-param name="input" select="n1third/@n1three3"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="cellCount" select="3"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With `writeRow` defined as follows:

```
<xsl:template name="writeRow">
  <xsl:param name="input"/>
  <xsl:param name="cellCount"/>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="$input[1]"/></td>
  <xsl:if test="$cellCount &gt; 1">
    <xsl:call-template name="writeRow">
       <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$input[position() &gt; 1]"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="cellCount" select="$cellCount - 1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

(Caution, might contain bugs)